# Calculated column in writable data grid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a datagrid in a VB.NET project which at present is directly bound to a binding source so changes get written straight to the underlying single table in the dataset.

I want to add a calculated column - a count of records on a linked table - while maintaining the ability to enter data directly in to the grid, which I lose if I use a query to get the current fields along with the calculated column.

Can anyone point me to the best way of doing this? Much appreciated as ever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've sorted it - an SQL subselect in the query in the dataset designer allowed me to do the count I needed while leaving the other fields writeable.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know that performing joins locks out all the fields, but subselects do not.